# Trying to read from a database using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to create a blog using Laravel 5.5 but I have received this error.

```
"Missing required parameters for [Route: posts.show] [URI: posts/{post}]. (View: /home/vagrant/Code/dialhousesetup.test/resources/views/posts/index.blade.php)"
```

On my postcontroller.php file. I did this so I can output all posts on my database:

```
public function index()
    {
        //Create a variable and store all the blog posts in it from the data base
        $posts = Post::all();

        //Return a view and pass in the above variable
        return view('posts.index', array('posts' => $posts));
    }
```

This is the loop I wrote on the /posts page to display all the blog posts.

```
<div class="events mb-100">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               @foreach ($posts as $post)
                <div class="col-md-6">
                   <a href="{{ route('posts.show'), $post->id }}">
                    <div class="single-event text-center">
                        <img src="http://www.dialhousehotel.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/CC_1419-The-Dial-House-website-01-18-04.jpg" alt="" style="border:2px solid #bb9b50;">
                        <h2>{{$post->title}}</h2>
                        <p>{{$post->main_body}}</p>
                        <div class="separator"></div>
                        <a href="{{ route('posts.show'), $post->id }}"><button type="submit" class="button button-simple mt-30">Read More</button></a>
                    </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
              @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I honestly don't know what I did wrong.

Update:
People have noticed there was a syntax issue and I have replaced {{ route('posts.show'), $post->id }} with {{ route('posts.show', $post->id) }}

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
                <div class="col-md-6">
                   <a href="{{ route('posts.show', $post->id) }}">
                    <div class="single-event text-center">
                        <img src="http://www.dialhousehotel.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/CC_1419-The-Dial-House-website-01-18-04.jpg" alt="" style="border:2px solid #bb9b50;">
                        <h2>{{$post->title}}</h2>
                        <p>{{$post->main_body}}</p>
                        <div class="separator"></div>
                        <a href="{{ route('posts.show', $post->id) }}"><button type="submit" class="button button-simple mt-30">Read More</button></a>
                    </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
              @endforeach
```

However, I am now getting an `"Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /home/vagrant/Code/dialhousesetup.test/resources/views/posts/index.blade.php)"`

```
<?php $__currentLoopData = $posts; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as $post): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                   <a href="<?php echo e(route('posts.show', $post->id)); ?>">
                    <div class="single-event text-center">
                        <img src="http://www.dialhousehotel.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/CC_1419-The-Dial-House-website-01-18-04.jpg" alt="" style="border:2px solid #bb9b50;">
                        <h2><?php echo e($post->title); ?></h2>
                        <p><?php echo e($post->main_body); ?></p>
                        <div class="separator"></div>
                        <a href="<?php echo e(route('posts.show', $post->id)); ?>"><button type="submit" class="button button-simple mt-30">Read More</button></a>
                    </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
              <?php endforeach; $__env->popLoop(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong syntax. Change it to:

```
{{ route('posts.show', $post->id) }}
```

Comment: sorry does {{ route('posts.show', $post->id) }} replace return view('posts.index', array('posts' => $posts)); ?

Comment: @JafarSalami no, it replaces this `{{ route('posts.show'), $post->id }}`

Comment: Thanks but now I get an Invalid argument supplied for foreach() error. I have updated the question

Comment: @JafarSalami it's not related to the original question. You should create a new one if you will not be able to handle it by yourself.

Comment: My bad. I figured it out the problem it was return view('posts.index', array('posts' => $posts)); . It should of been return view('posts.index')->withPosts($posts); My apologies.

Comment: @JafarSalami `return view('posts.index')->withPosts($posts);` does exactly the same as `return view('posts.index', array('posts' => $posts));`. And the probem for 100% was in the `route()` helper in the form.

Answer (score 0):

The error is here.

```
<a href="{{ route('posts.show'), $post->id }}">
```

It needs the ID to be part of the route. So it would be

```
<a href="{{ route('posts.show', $post->id) }}">
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.